# R: how to use get and set functions in a package?

Tags: r

I am trying my hand at R, along with RStudio and I am currently stuck. Is it possible to create an R package with a variable visible only inside of that package? I was unable to find comprehensive examples on the web.

Here's a small example:

```
gEnv <- new.env()

a <- ""
b <- "Beta"
assign(a, "alpha", envir=gEnv)
assign(b, "beta", envir=gEnv)

getA <- function()
{
  return(get(a, envir=gEnv))
}

getB <- function()
{
  return(get(b, envir=gEnv))
}

setA <- function(x)
{
  return(assign(a, x, envir=gEnv))
}

setB <- function(x)
{
  return(assign(b, x, envir=gEnv))
}
```

When I try to 'Build & Reload', I get the following error:

```
==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source globalVar

* installing to library 'C:/Users/*masked*/Documents/R/win-library/3.2'
* installing *source* package 'globalVar' ...
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in assign(a, "alpha", envir = gEnv) : 
  attempt to use zero-length variable name
Error : unable to load R code in package 'globalVar'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'globalVar'
* removing 'C:/Users/*masked*/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/globalVar'

Exited with status 1.
```

How can the above code be changed to successfully build a package, from which I can later call `setA("apple")` and `getA()` would actually return `[1] "apple"`?

Comment: You might want to look into S4 for object oriented programming in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a closure like so:

```
getterSetter<-  function(){

    # define a variable X in the current closure
    x = NULL

    # return a list with two functions:

    list(# The first function returns the value of X defined 
         # when `getterSetter` is called
         get=function()x,
         # and the second function uses the scoping assignment operator to 
         # assign to the variable
         set=function(x)x <<-x)
}


A = getterSetter()
B = getterSetter()

A$set('apple')
B$set('banana')

A$get()
#> [1] "apple"
B$get()
#> [1] "banana"
```

Answer (score 1):

Environments can be accessed similar to lists, this allows you to avoid using `get` and `assign` and can make everything simpler.  I think you might have the arguments in your `assign` calls reversed.  Are you really trying to create a variable with no name ("") with the value "alpha"? or are you trying to create a variable named "alpha" and give it the value in a ("")?

Try these alternatives:

```
gEnv <- new.env()

a <- ""
b <- "Beta"
gEnv[['alpha']] <- a
gEnv[['beta']] <- b

getA <- function()
{
  return(gEnv[['alpha']])
}

getB <- function()
{
  return(gEnv[['beta']])
}

setA <- function(x)
{
  gEnv[['alpha']] <- x
}

setB <- function(x)
{
  gEnv[['beta']] <- x
}
```